# NSURLSession task not running

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, nsurlrequest, nsurlsessiondatatask

I'm trying to use `NSURLSession` to get ID's from a url, but the code between `let task = NSURLSession....` and `task.resume` is never executed (I placed a breakpoint inside to check, as you can see in the attached image).

What am I missing?

```
func getPlayingSongData() {
    while loopItem < IDsForSongsToPlay.count {
        self.getPlayingSongDataLoop()
        loopItem++
    }

    self.stream()
}

func getPlayingSongDataLoop() {
    playerStatus = "Paused"

    let songIDToGet = IDsForSongsToPlay[loopItem]

    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://url.com/ajax.php?call=song&id=\(songIDToGet)")!
    print(url)

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data:NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

        // Convert Json data into an Array
        let songID:[String:String] = (try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)) as! [String:String]

        print(songID["id"]!)
        self.StreamIDsForSongs.append((songID["id"]!))
        songPlaying = songID["title"]!
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

UPDATE:

I changed

> let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data:NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

to

> let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) in

and then it worked for me.

[My code with breakpoints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8EOB.png)

Comment: Is the call serviced on the server side? I compared your code to mine and it looks correct. (I would add some error checking in case the returned data is empty.) My guess is that the server side code is bad, maybe not returning anything.

Comment: By the way, it's really not a good idea to use `try!` to process a network response. You almost certainly don't want your app crashing if there's some network error outside of your control.

Comment: Regarding your update, that's almost certainly not the real issue. There's something else going on. If it worked after that change, it's undoubtedly merely a coincidence. The issue rests elsewhere.

Comment: I'll keep playing with it.  The issue before wasn't that it didn't return anything, but that the code inside the task wasn't even being executed.

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple the function [dataTaskWithURL(_:completionHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLSession/dataTaskWithURL:completionHandler:):

> Creates a task that retrieves the contents of the specified URL, then calls a handler upon completion.

If the request completes successfully, the `data` parameter of the completion handler block contains the resource data, and the `error` parameter is `nil`. If the request fails, the data parameter is `nil` and the `error` parameter contain information about the failure.

Then you should see the values for each parameter regarding your request.

I hope this help you.